# No such element exception

Tags: java

The `ch` variable is not recognised by the while loop although it is declared outside the loop.  Why?  There is no compilation error.

```
package calculator;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int ch;
        do {
            System.out.print("ENTER YOUR CHOICE : ");
            ch = s.nextInt();
            switch (ch) {
                case 1: {
                }
                .....
                default: {
                    System.out.println("\n!!!ENTER VALID CHOICE !!!");
                    break;
                }
            }
        } while (ch != 9);
        s.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: ... so what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

1. This code is working fine. elements of parent block are always visible.
2. Don't use break in `default` case

**Your code :**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int ch;
        do {
            System.out.print("ENTER YOUR CHOICE : ");
            ch = s.nextInt();
            switch (ch) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("one");
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("\n!!!ENTER VALID CHOICE !!!");
            }
        } while (ch != 9);
        s.close();
    }
}
```

*Only the edit I made was I removed `break` from `default` block.

**Running Example :**

```
ENTER YOUR CHOICE : 1
one
ENTER YOUR CHOICE : 2

!!!ENTER VALID CHOICE !!!
ENTER YOUR CHOICE : 3

!!!ENTER VALID CHOICE !!!
ENTER YOUR CHOICE : 9

!!!ENTER VALID CHOICE !!!
```

Comment: ENTER YOUR CHOICE : Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source) at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source) at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source) at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source) at calculator.Calculation.main(Calculation.java:29)

Comment: only 1 time executes then doesn't wait for the choice

Comment: problem in: ch = s.nextInt();

Comment: Code is perfectly fine. There might be other thing because of which it is not working. I edited my post to show you a running example.

Comment: i hve also done the same...created 1 sample program to check do-while loop...and its working...but whats the problem with my code...not able to understand...

Answer (score 0):

put your break statement of default case outside the braces. I think that is your problem. I tried the below code and gives me the output.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class HelloWorld {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int ch;
    do  { 
        System.out.print("ENTER YOUR CHOICE : ");
        ch=s.nextInt();
        switch(ch)
        {
            case 1: 
                System.out.println("one");
            break;
            default: 
                System.out.println("\n!!!ENTER VALID CHOICE !!!");
            break;
        }
    }while(ch!=9);
    s.close();
   }
}
```

Comment: ENTER YOUR CHOICE : Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
 at calculator.Calculation.main(Calculation.java:29)

Comment: only 1 time executes then doesn't wait for the choice

Comment: problem in:  ch = s.nextInt();

Comment: This code is perfect! I don't understand what is the error.